# Session is invalid with oauth when trying to authenticate with twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, twitter, oauth

I am seeing this error when trying to set up oauth for twitter  (steps
outlined in http://oauth.rubyforge.org/ for more info)

1. using consumer to get request_token
2. saving request_token in a session
3. Error when twitter returns to the callback_url because this session
   is NOT the session I used in step 2. above to save the request_token.
4. Since I don't have request_token available, I can't use make the
   call to get access_token.

Anyone seen this before?  Any ideas on how/why this is happening? Why
is the session a new/different one?

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#oauth_callback

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.get_access_token
```

Thanks.